# How to test on destroy scope

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

How to unit testing an $destroy event of a Directive in angularjs?

I have the code in my directive:

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    //clean something
});
```

My test code:

```
it('on destroy',function(){
    scope.$destroy();
    scope.$digest();

    //expect everything done?
});
```

Any suggestion!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can select the DOM from the template of your directive and get the scope of it, then run $destroy().

Ex:

your tpl:

```
"<div id='tuna'></div>"
```

your test:

```
it('test on destroy', function(){
  var isolateScope = $(element).find('#tuna').eq(0).scope();
  isolateScope.$destroy();
})
```

Hope help you!

Answer (score 11):

You should test the code that is executed within the `$destroy` event. Here's a contrived example using a controller:

**Test**

```
it('sets destroyed to true when the scope is destroyed', function() {
  // Arrange
  $scope.destroyed = false;

  // Act
  $scope.$destroy();

  // Assert
  expect($scope.destroyed).toBe(true);
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.destroyed = true;
  });
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hEj6fYcES81UDLzEvsdL?p=preview).

Comment: hi Michael! i think your solution for scope in the controller. I want test $destroy of scope in a directive. thank!

Comment: I think it's the same solution for a directive. Could you create a Plunker script with your code?

Comment: This is practical. I'm curious if there any built-in boolean flag to check the state. In other words, AngularJS itself will destroy a scope only once by checking particular boolean flag?

Answer (score 1):

Angular's `isolateScope` is preferable to using jQuery. You've probably compiled the element in a beforeEach above your test like this:

```
myEl = '<div my-el>MY EL</div>';
scope = $rootScope.$new();
directiveElement = $compile(myEl)(scope);
scope.$digest();
```

Now in your test you can access the `isolateScope` and call `$destroy`:

```
var isolated = directiveElement.isolateScope();
isolated.$destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

```
var destroyed = spyOn(scope, '$destroy').and.callThrough();
scope.$destroy();
expect(destroyed).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

unlike other answers I don't have to create *flag* variables that only make sense for testing, also, it makes more sense to me to use Jasmine spyOn and callThrough to check if the function $destry is being successfully called.